# Reinitialized variable in the class?

Tags: java

When I have declared the variable in the interface so it becomes `public static final` then how I am able to change the value of `a` in my class ?

```
interface xyz{
   int a=1;
}

class Test2 implements xyz{
   public static int a=123;
}    

class Test1{
   public static void main(String aa[]){
      System.out.println(Test2.a);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable. Per the linked wikipedia entry,

> In [computer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming), **variable shadowing** occurs when a variable declared within a certain [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) (decision block, method, or inner class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.

In your example, you are creating a new variable named `a`. It has nothing to do with the `a` declared in the interface.

```
System.out.println(((xyz) new Test2()).a);
```

would still output `1`.

Comment: Thakyou @Elliott Frisch